# Possible to run custom app inside native FB app?

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile

We're developing a Facebook app for a client. Primary for the web but most users in Scandinavia access FB through their mobile. Conventional wisdom seems to dictate that Custom Facebook Apps does not work inside the native FB app on mobile devices. Is that still true?

Just to clarify: I'm talking about Facebook Apps found under a Page Tab.

Answer (score 2):

You can make separate app for mobile users and two ways to forward user to mobile app

1.use facebook app settings and add mobile app settings

2.when user come on main page trace that user comes from mobile or web if from mobile then forward it to mobile app

Comment: THX! So, Facebook (HTML) Apps CAN exist INSIDE the Facebook native app?

Comment: Seeing is believing: Does anybody know of an app that runs inside Fabebook's native app.

Comment: @TOMvonMOM there is many but i suggest official way and its add mobile app settings on fb app setiings

Comment: Just one example will do ;-)